# Time complexity : simple loop calculation

Tags: time-complexity

I have a simple loop like this :

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  // constant time operation
}
```

It’s very easy to see that it’s of O(n) time complexity, but if we calculate it, why is it `2*n + 2 + c*n` (given answer) and not `(1+ (n+1) + 2*n + c*n) = (3+c)*n + 2`? I see `i++` as 2 operations: addition and assignment; thus, it should be `2*n`, and the constant operation is executed `n` times, so it’s `c*n`.

Answer (score 0):

```
2*n
```

(`n` comparisons (`i<n`)
+ `n` increments (`i++`)) `== 2*n`

```
2
```

(`i=0` `1` for assignment
+ `1` for allocation of `i`) `== 2`

```
c*n
```

(`n` constant time operations) `== c*n`

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, increment/decrement is treated as a single operation. This makes sense because in assembly, you can perform an increment or decrement with a single line of assembly code. Furthermore, most lines of assembly code translate directly to a single binary instruction. Thus, increment/decrement is effectively a constant time operation.

Therefore, we have n operations from incrementing. We also run the body of the loop n times, and the body of the loop performs a constant time operation, so we have an additional c * n operations. When we enter the loop the first time, there is an additional assignment operation. This yields another operation. Finally, after the loop runs the nth time, the loop checks the condition of the loop one more time. This means there are n + 1 comparisons that the loop performs.

Adding these up, we have n + c * n + 1 + (n + 1) = 2 * n + c * n + 2, which is the answer you saw.